# Terminal Server Install -- Add/Remove Program Message on NonAdministrator Machines

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

First time poster...

My company uses terminal services for one of our remote offices. Data is kept on a different server. OS is Windows Server 2003. Last week, they needed to purchase a program and have it installed on terminal server, which was done. An administrator session was started, the TS was put into install mode and the program was installed. The TS was then put back into execute mode. The install did not require a reboot.

Since then, when any user who does not have administrator privileges initiates a remote session and logs in they get a security message that says "Add / Remove programs has been restricted. Please contact your system administrator." The only option is to click OK, which everyone does and after that there are no issues.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything in runonce or run in the registry?

Comment: That is in local machine as well?